# How Splitting Summation method works

Tags: algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, approximation

I'm reading Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, *Introduction to Algorithms*, Appendix A, page 1152. They discuss a method called "Splitting Summations", where they split the summation and bound each term separately. For example,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k &= \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} k + \sum_{k=n/2 + 1}^{n} k\\
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} 0 + \sum_{k=n/2 + 1}^{n} (n/2)\\
&= (n/2)^2\\
&= \Omega(n^2)\,\end{align*}$$

I didn't understand step 2 where they have replaced $k$ with $0$ in one part and $k$ with $n/2$ in other. How does this method work? Can anybody explain?

Comment: In the second line, notice that it starts with $\ge$.

Comment: what book is CLRS?

Comment: @miracle173 Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, _Introduction to Algorithms_, MIT Press. This is actually a pretty standard abbreviation in the computer science community: if you Google for "CLRS", all the top hits refer to the right thing. (I'm not criticizing you for not Googling; just presenting evidence why using the abbreviation isn't crazy.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You are right but maybe the result is a different if you google in five years or if you use duckduckgo or if you live in Kazakhstan

Comment: @miracle173, I very much doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
55 = 1 + 2 + \dots + 10 &= (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) + (6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10)\\
&\color{red}{\geq} (0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0) + (5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5) \\
&= (10/2)(10/2) = 25\,.\end{align*}$$

If you're wondering how to come up with such substitutions, there's no general method: this is one of the creative things you have to do to produce mathematical proofs.